# Concave functions inequalities

Tags: functions

If we have a differentiable concave function $u(x)$ defined on $p$ and $x$, such that $u(x_1) > u(x_2)$,

Does the concavity and differentiability of the function in any way imply that:

$u(x_1) \leq u(x_2) + Du(x_1)(x_2-x_1)$?

I can't seem to understand any property of concave functions that implies this, even though the paper i'm going through deems it kinda trivial.

Comment: Do you know how to show a related property for convex functions? Maybe this is more familiar to you.

Comment: The only property that this form of equation reminds me of is that the function of a average (in case of concave functions) is less than the average of the functions. Is this equation somehow derived from that?

Comment: Try to use the definition of concavity and write down a difference quotient